# What is the difference between 타고나다 and 태어나다?

Tags: difference, verb

Both of these words - 타고나다 and 태어나다 seem to mean "be born". This pair seems to not be in the category of transitive/intransitive verb which is common in Korean.

Also, both seem to be often used to modify a noun. But what is the difference between them and how should I use them apart correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

타고나다 is not just "be born" - **X를 타고나다** means "to be born with X (some quality)".

> 직관력을 타고난 사람 - a person born with (good) intuition
>
> 타고난 천재 - a natural born genius
>
> 타고난 게으름을 고칠 방법은? - How can [I] fix the laziness [I] was born with?
>
> 타고난 성격은 고칠 수 없다 - You can't change one's born nature.  (= "You can't fix a person.")

태어나다 is a more simple "be born".

> 어머니는 1967년에 태어나셨다. = My mom was born in 1967.

Comment: Thanks. Another question: why is the third sentence not 고치는? I thought the form to modify a noun is add 는 after the stem of the verb...

Comment: That's only part of a story: a verb can use -는/-ㄴ/-ㄹ to modify nouns, which corresponds to present/past/future. E.g., 출발하는 기차 (a train that's departing), 출발한 기차 (a train that departed), 출발할 기차 (a train that will depart). For the particular sentence in the text, 고치는 방법 & 고칠 방법 will both work. (If you say 고친 방법 then it would mean you already overcame your laziness and you want to talk about how you did it.)